# sum value on sql with one column

Tags: mysql

can you help me, I create API if I have table looks like(example) :

```
--------------------------------
id nominal kategori tanggal 
15  20000    -1     2000-11-13
16 10000      1     2000-11-16
17 15000      1     2000-12-25
18 18000     -1     2000-12-28
```

and I want to output like(example) ???

```
{
  January:
  income : 2000
  output : 1000
  result : 1000

  February:
  March   :
  April   :


  lastYear :
  incomeAllMonth:
  outputallMonth:
  resultAllMonth
}
```

thanks

Comment: the code you did. Please add that to your post.Then only we can help (edit your question and add that code)

Comment: How do the column names in your table relate to the desired output? The names are different, so it is unclear.